# Creating/Using Dynamic AppDomain Objects

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain

I have recently begun creating custom `DLLs` to load into `Wonderware`'s `ArchestrA IDE` to add functionality and flexibility to my applications. With this idea, I was wanting to create datatables within the `AppDomain` to be accessible throughout the application but I cannot find a good example of how to do this.

My question here is:

How do I, from inside my `DLL`, create/use dynamic properties within the current `AppDomain`?

I know that `SetData(string, object)` and `GetData(string)` exist within the `AppDomain` but does this allow the creation of new dynamic properties?

Comment: AppDomain does.  It's not really properties from the point of view of OO but rather just write-once _key-value_ pairs

Comment: Is this question about how to generate custom classes with custom properties? Phrasing kinda confuses me...

Comment: If having to load a custom class into the AppDomain gets me the DataTable I require then that may be the answer to my question and another area to gather information on. However, I really only NEED a single DataTable to pass Batch info from on symbol to another in Wonderware. All symbols share the same AppDomain within the View app.